# autoregister new teamcity build agent via API

Tags: api, automation, teamcity, ansible

We use Ansible to configure build agent for different technology stacks like: frontend builder(Nodejs, libs, Dart SDK), backend builder(JDK), etc with Ansible orchestration tool and that easy to replace one linux with another be configuring new one from zero with orchestration except new teamcity agent registration.

Is it piossible to generate new `authorizationToken` for new agent with API call which can be used in programming language or register new agent via API call to be able to connect new linux box without Admin/human ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's REST API call to achieve this, just pass `true` or `false` string as request data via `PUT` request to the  `/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/<agentLocator>/authorized`, `<agentLocator>` syntax is described [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-Locator).

Here's an example of a `curl` command:

```
curl -X PUT "http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/id:3/authorized" --data true --header "Content-Type: text/plain" -u user:pass
```

`PUT` method should be used and `Content-Type: text/plain` header should be provided.